# Processing: running draw cycle into an independent thread

Tags: processing, java-threads

**QUESTION**

I've noticed that `draw()` cycle is interrupted by events elaboration.
In the following example the circle animation will stop at mouse click until the `elaborating_function()` ends.

```
void setup(){
  
  size(800, 600);
  background(#818B95);
  frameRate(30);
}

void draw(){  
  
    background(#818B95);  
    
    //simple animation 
    fill(0,116,217);  
    circle(circle_x, 200, 50);
    
    circle_x += animation_speed;
    if(circle_x>800){ circle_x = 0; }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  
  elaborating_function();
}

void elaborating_function(){
  println("elaboration start");
  delay(1000);
  println("elaboration end");
}
```

Of course, a simple solution to run the elaboration without stopping the animation could be to `thread("elaborating_function");`

But my question is: if it is possible to run the draw cycle into an independent thread instead?

**SOLUTION**

I've found a possible solution inverting my problem and creating an "*independent cycle*" parallel to the `draw` one. Within this cycle is possible to run any function and it will not interfere with the draw execution. Every event triggered by the user needs only to set a specific variable in order to activate (once or more time) the function within the cycle.

```
int circle_x = 0;
int animation_speed = 5;

boolean call_elaborating_function = false;

void setup(){
  
  size(800, 600);
  background(#818B95);
  frameRate(30);
  
  IndependentCycle independentCycle = new IndependentCycle();
  independentCycle.setFrequency(1);
  new Thread(independentCycle).start();
}

void draw(){  
  
    background(#818B95);  
    
    //simple animation 
    fill(0,116,217);  
    circle(circle_x, 200, 50);
    
    circle_x += animation_speed;
    if(circle_x>800){ circle_x = 0; }
}

public class IndependentCycle implements Runnable{
  
  private int frequency; //execution per seconds
  
  public IndependentCycle(){
    
    frequency = 0;
  }
  
  public void setFrequency(int frequency){
    this.frequency = 1000/frequency;
    println(this.frequency);
  }
  
  public void run(){
    
    while(true){
      print(".");
      delay(this.frequency);
          
      //DO STUFF HERE
      //WITH IF EVENT == ture IN ORDER TO RUN JUST ONCE !!
      if(call_elaborating_function){
        call_elaborating_function = false;
        elaborating_function();
      }
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  
  call_elaborating_function = true;
}

void elaborating_function(){
  println("elaboration start");
  delay(1000);
  println("elaboration end");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Processing has it's own [AnimationThread](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/a6e0e227a948e7e2dc042c04504d6f5b8cf0c1a6/core/src/processing/core/PSurfaceNone.java#L249).

Your proposed solution to thread `elaborating_function()` is great.
You could have a basic class that `implements Runnable` if you need a bit more control. With this thread running in parallel, Processing's main animation thread should run along side it just fine without pausing rendering.

This options sounds much simpler than trying to mess with Processing's `AnimationThread` and potentially have to deal with unexpected behaviour.
What is the actual goal you're trying achieve ?

Comment: I've tried to implement a Runnable class to run my elaborating_function() as you suggested, but it behaves the same interrupting the draw cycle.
I believe it is due to the way the user's event triggers some interrupts within the program execution. 
Anyway, I've reversed the problem by running another independent thread cycle and leaving the events the only task to update a boolean variable-trigger for the actions within this cycle.
It is a little convoluted, but works.

Comment: That sounds like a sensible solution (using a boolean to "debounce" the state to trigger the function). (The one minor thing I'd like to point out is this: `frequency = 0;`. You might want a different default to avoid division by zero in case an instance is accidentally called without setting a frequency > 0) Nice work!